# Etiquette regarding widening an Area51 proposal?

Tags: discussion, area-51

It's been suggested that I widen my proposed site, [3D-modeling](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-modeling-techniques-and-software), to encompass all of Computer Graphics development. However, I'm not sure if there are any issues of etiquette (or is ethics a better word?), for two reasons. First, there is already such a site, [Computer Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7287/cg-computer-graphics) - which, however, only has a dozen followers.

Second, is it okay to keep *changing* a site proposal, if I have before? I started my proposal originally as a *Blender 3D* site, and it went no-where - so I widened it, and it's managed to reach 60+ followers. However, we still don't have 5/5 on/off-topic Questions, and I have doubts about enough karma for the *commitment* phase, also :)

So it is reasonable to widen it again?

Comment: I don't think you should, personally. 3D modeling is a specific skillset that doesn't really overlap with graphic design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I'll put up an answer, just to close it out :) At this point, the question is OBE (overcome by events), as it's in Commitment phase. And although there is discussion of widening it again, it seems that I can't *edit* the proposal text in Commitment phase, so that's no longer an option.